# Django Management Command best practice for additional file location

Tags: django

I am writing a Django management command. The command itself is located under `myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py`. I need to write an additional class which I would like to place in an extra file.

Should this file live in

- `myapp/extrafile.py` or
- `myapp/management/commands/extrafile.py`

What would be a recommended location. The class is only need for the management command, not elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional file in `myapp/management/commands/` that **starts with underscore**. It is not going to be detected as a management command (check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)).

So, your command in: `myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py`

And your helper in: `myapp/management/commands/_myhelper.py`

Answer (score -1):

Generally in these cases you are writing a helper file for that file so You can create a helper folder like this:

```
myapp
-helpers
--commands
--other_helpers
```

you can read more about helpers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_class), they can be separated from the original class/function.

Comment: In Django managements command are located at `appname/management/commands/`.

Comment: I know but your helper files can be under a helper module in app folder, unless you have a specific helper which you want to put beside the commands folder to only use in commands folder.